# 2 minutes latency on worker send back result with celery, redis and rabbitMQ

Tags: azure, docker, redis, rabbitmq, celery

**What I have**:

I run celery with rabbitMQ as a broker and redis as the result backend. I have an app that sends tasks and workers that process the tasks.

I deployed this as follow:

- The app, redis, rabbitMQ and a worker (let's call him 'local_worker') are running on an azure VM using a docker-compose so I use the docker version of rabbitMQ and redis (6.2.5). rabbitMQ and redis ports are open on the VM and those containers are configured with username and password.
- I add workers using azure container instances that connects to the redis and rabbitMQ running on the VM.

First if you have recommendation on this architecture I would be glad to get advice.

**The problem**:

Everything works well, the tasks are dispatched on the different workers which send back the results etc etc...

When a task is sent after 30 minutes with no task running I observe redis latency of 2 minutes when the task is not sent to the 'local_worker'.

- I know this must come from redis because I can see the logs of the task in the worker container instance immediately after sending the task.
- I monitor this architecture with flower and graphana with celery prometheus exporter so I can monitor the latency of the tasks. On flower the latent task stays with the 'processing' status.
- There is exactly 120 seconds more on a task which is the first one after a no task interval and which is not processed by the 'local_worker'.
- This does not happen when the task is processed by the 'local_worker' which runs on the same VM as redis.

It is like redis or the VM was sleeping for 2 minutes before sending back the result. As it is exactly 120 seconds (2 minutes) I expect that it is something wanted by redis, celery or azure (something deterministic)

I don't use a redis conf file, only default settings (except for the password) to run the redis server.

Thanks for your help and feedback on my architecture and problems.

Here is a screenshot of what I see in flower. The three tasks are the same (removing a directory).
[image: My flower view of tasks that have been sent with a 25 minutes delay (the three tasks are the same).]

The first and the third tasks have been processed by the local worker. The second one has been processed by an external worker. On the logs of the external worker I put a print line just befor returning the results and this line has been printed at 14:14:23. So there has been 120 seconds between this print and the official end of the task.

EDIT:

I found that the default value for redis_socket_timeout was 120 seconds.

I removed the line `redis_retry_on_timeout = True` and added the line `redis_socket_keepalive = True` in my celery config file. Now the error I get is that the task failed with `redis.exceptions.TimeoutError: Timeout reading from socket`.
I don't know why the socket times out whereas the result is ready. Is it a problem with the network of my container instance?

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.5"
services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.rabbitmq-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=15672
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-http.rule=(Host(`rabbitmq.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`))
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-https.rule=Host(`rabbitmq.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`)
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.rabbitmq-ui-http.middlewares=https-redirect
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}

    networks:
      - traefik-public


  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.5
    restart: always
    command: ["redis-server", "--requirepass", "${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-password}"]
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - traefik-public

  flower:
    image: mher/flower:0.9.5
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.flower-ui.loadbalancer.server.port=5555
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-http.rule=Host(`flower.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-https.rule=Host(`flower.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`)
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-http.middlewares=https-redirect

      - traefik.http.routers.flower-ui-https.middlewares=traefik-admin-auth

    env_file:
      - .env
    command:
      - "--broker=amqp://${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER:-guest}:${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-guest}@rabbitmq:5672//"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis

    networks:
      - traefik-public

  local_worker:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./setup/devops/docker/app.dockerfile
    image: swtools:app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${SWTOOLSWORKINGDIR:-/tmp}:${SWTOOLSWORKINGDIR:-/tmp}
    command: ["celery", "--app=app.worker.celery_app:celery_app", "worker", "-n", "local_worker@%h"]
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - REDIS_HOST=${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
    networks:
      - traefik-public

  dashboard_app:
    image: swtools:app
    restart: always
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.services.dash-app.loadbalancer.server.port=${DASH_PORT-8080}
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-http.rule=Host(`dashboard.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`)
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-https.rule=Host(`dashboard.${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}.example.app`)
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-http.middlewares=https-redirect

      - traefik.http.middlewares.operator-auth.basicauth.users=${OPERATOR_USERNAME?Variable not set}:${HASHED_OPERATOR_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
      - traefik.http.routers.dash-app-https.middlewares=operator-auth

    volumes:
      - ${SWTOOLSWORKINGDIR:-/tmp}:${SWTOOLSWORKINGDIR:-/tmp}

    command: ['waitress-serve', '--port=${DASH_PORT:-8080}', 'app.order_dashboard:app.server']
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
      - RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - REDIS_HOST=${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - redis
networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
```

and my celery config file:

```
import os
import warnings
from pathlib import Path

# result backend use redis
result_backend_host = os.getenv('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost')
result_backend_pass = os.getenv('REDIS_PASS', 'password')

result_backend = 'redis://:{password}@{host}:6379/0'.format(password=result_backend_pass, host=result_backend_host)


# redis_retry_on_timeout = True
redis_socket_keepalive = True

# broker use rabbitmq
rabbitmq_user = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER', 'guest')
rabbitmq_pass = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS', 'guest')
rabbitmq_host = os.getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST', 'localhost')




broker_url = 'amqp://{user}:{password}@{host}:5672//'.format(user=rabbitmq_user, password=rabbitmq_pass, host=rabbitmq_host)


include = ['app.worker.tasks', 'app.dashboard.example1', 'app.dashboard.example2']


#task events
worker_send_task_events = True
task_send_sent_event = True
```

All the env variables are defined and it works well except my socket timeout problem! When I deploy a new worker on a container instance, I set the env variables so it connects to the rabbitmq and redis running on the docker-compose.

Here is my celery file that defines the celery app:

```
from celery import Celery
from app.worker import celery_config

celery_app = Celery()
celery_app.config_from_object(celery_config)
```

Comment: How did you measure those 2 mins? in flower? trying to retrieving results in code?

Comment: Yes with flower! It lasts exactly 120s more than the task running without this latency

Comment: flower peeks at the events and doesn't use the backend (Redis) - can you edit the question and add a screenshot that shows those 2 mins in flower?

Comment: I updated the description and put a screenshot. Thanks for your concern!

Comment: To ensure it's not something you did, I would recommend adding some signals (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#task-postrun) - just add logs to ensure where it stuck

Comment: I edited my question as I found that the default socket timeout was 120 seconds and it matches my 120 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally changing the backend to rpc resolved the problem. I tried different things with redis that didn't work. A way to dig would be to inspect the sockets with tcp-dump to see where it blocks but I didn't try that I my problem was solved with the rpc backend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have some firewall between your Redis instance and your worker.
Can you login to that `SandboxHost...` and ensure that you can connect your redis?

You can do that with `telnet`, for example:

```
telnet <your_redis_hostname> <your_redis_port>
```

or with redis-cli:

```
redis-cli -h <your_redis_hostname> -p <your_redis_port>
```

**EDIT**:

Seems like you're missing [result_backend](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#conf-redis-result-backend):

```
result_backend = f"redis://username:{result_backend_pass}@{result_backend_host}:6379/0"
```

and make sure that your `REDIS_HOST=${HOSTNAME?Variable not set}` is valid...

**EDIT2**:

Can you add the `bind` to your Redis command:

```
["redis-server", "--bind", "0.0.0.0", "--requirepass", "${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS:-password}"]
```

Please be aware of its security implications!

Comment: as it is a container I can-t connect to it and use this command. I try to connect my own machine as a worker and I will see if I have the issue too. If I have I will be able to run these commands.

Comment: Your machine might configured differently, can't you exec into your container? Not familiar with azure containers but seems like you can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

Comment: And it's just for isolating the problem. I wonder how you do have access to rabbitmq and not to redis, are they running on containers as well?

Comment: Thanks for your resource I didn't think that I could run a command from a running container. I will try it. Rabbitmq and redis are both running on containers inside a docker-compose in my virtual machine.

Comment: Can you share your docker compose file + your celery redis configuration (instantiation of Celery)

Comment: I have the exact same problem when running the container on my machine. I can try your command from the container running on azure or on my machine but the problem is that neither redis-cli or telnet is installed on the container. I can run it from my machine outside of the container and it connects well. I will edit my question and show you the docker-compose and the celery config file.

Comment: @Charles where is celery? something like: `app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')`

Comment: Celery is called on another file I edited my question again with this file

Comment: look at my answer, your missing the `result_backend`

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy this line but I just added it. The `REDIS_HOST` variable is valid as the worker can send back the results when I set `redis_retry_on_timeout = True` and as it works well when I have no socket timeout problem. I think this is a socket problem. It works like if the worker wait for the socket to timeout before sending the results so when I set `redis_retry_on_timeout = True` it works with 120s latency but when I don't set it it fails because the socket times out.

Comment: I lost you, sorry. How can backend (Redis) work if you didn't set it host (which is in your case = `redis` which is the service name)

Comment: I can set it with the service name in the docker compose or with the dns name of my virtual machine for example. Here the env variable HOSTNAME is defined as the dns name on my virtual machine and when I deploy a new worker I set the REDIS_HOST variable to the dns name of my virtual machine running redis (the port 6379 is open on this machine)

Comment: That's a wrong way IMO. You shouldn't (and you don't need) open the port out. you can use the service name and connect internally via the docker network

Comment: yes but if I want to connect external worker, how should I do then?

Comment: @Charles see my second edit of the answer, maybe it would help

Comment: I get the exact same error even with `"--bind" "0.0.0.0"` in the command of my redis container in the compose. Do you think this is not a good practice to connect remote workers by opening the redis port? I did that because I need specific worker for example worker with a GPU that can't run on the same instance as redis and my compose but if you have other ideas I would be glad to hear it!

Comment: right, sounds like your instance firewall (the one that run the docker-compose) should accept all interfaces ( aka `0.0.0.0`) for port 6379. Can you try the `telnet` command in the instance with the GPUs? (should be easy to install, something like: `apt-get update && apt-get install -y telnet`)

Comment: I get this when running telnet inside my container : 
`Trying <ip-adress>... Connected to <my-dns-name>. Escape character is '^]'`If there was a firewall maybe every task should fail no? For now I have tasks that works and tasks that fails with a timeout on the worker

Comment: that's good! are you doing it from the `worker1@Sandbox..` right?

Comment: Yes from the `worker1@Sandbox..`

Comment: So my container running as a worker can connect to the redis on the virtual machines but socket expires. Maybe I shoud try another backend results like rpc